# Getting JSON from URL and then display results in accordion using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created an accordion which I would like to populate using JSON from this link : http://design.propcom.co.uk/buildtest/accordion-data.json

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="accordion js-accordion">
        <div class="accordion__item js-accordion-item active">
            <div class="accordion-header js-accordion-header"></div> 
            <div class="accordion-body js-accordion-body" >
                <div class="accordion-body__contents" ></div>
            </div><!-- end of accordion body -->
        </div><!-- end of accordion item -->

    <div class="accordion__item js-accordion-item ">
        <div class="accordion-header js-accordion-header"></div> 
            <div class="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
                <div class="accordion-body__contents"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="accordion__item js-accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-header js-accordion-header"></div> 
            <div class="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
                <div class="accordion-body__contents"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of accordion -->
```

I am trying to populate the **accordion-header js-accordion-header** div with the "heading" data from the JSON file and **accordion-body__contents** with the "contents" data.

This is as far as I have got with the Javascript part:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://design.propcom.co.uk/buildtest/accordion-data.json',   
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'JSON',
success: function (data) {
   $.each(data.blocks, function(index, element) {
   $(".accordion-header").append("<div>" + element.heading + "</div>");
   $(".accordion-body__contents").append("<div>" + element.content + "</div>");
    });
}
```

});

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I feel like I've hit a wall with my current efforts.

Comment: Are you receiving the data? Inside the AJAX?

Comment: Just remove: `jsonCallback: 'callback',`.

Comment: So you have an element `<js-accordion-header>` in your HTML? Your selector is looking for an element with a class of accordion-header and inside of that an element with the tag of js-accordion-header.

Comment: I can see the data if I display it in the console, I just can't get it to display in the html. I have amended the selector and the <h2> tags show but no data is displayed inside.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. We're a bit off when handling the AJAX results

   - Use the `data.blocks` property and while looping use the `element` variable.
2. As @Danny suggested we have extra AJAX properties

   - Remove the `callback` and `data` properties.
3. *Lastly your html seems over complicated*

   - After seeing the css from your demo site, I was able to include it and remove the JQueryUI thought. Now be sure to append the entire `accordion__item` element.

With these problems ironed out it should look similar to this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://design.propcom.co.uk/buildtest/accordion-data.json',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.blocks, function(index, element) {
      $(".accordion")
        .append(`<div class="accordion__item js-accordion-item ">
          <div class="accordion-header js-accordion-header">${element.heading}</div> 
              <div class="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
                  <div class="accordion-body__contents">${element.content}</div>
              </div>
          </div>`);
    });
    
    var accordion = (function(){
      var $accordion = $('.js-accordion');
      var $accordion_header = $accordion.find('.js-accordion-header');
      var $accordion_item = $('.js-accordion-item');

      // default settings 
      var settings = {
        // animation speed
        speed: 400,

        // close all other accordion items if true
        oneOpen: false
      };

      return {
        // pass configurable object literal
        init: function($settings) {
          $accordion_header.on('click', function() {
            accordion.toggle($(this));
          });

          $.extend(settings, $settings); 

          // ensure only one accordion is active if oneOpen is true
          if(settings.oneOpen && $('.js-accordion-item.active').length > 1) {
            $('.js-accordion-item.active:not(:first)').removeClass('active');
          }

          // reveal the active accordion bodies
          $('.js-accordion-item.active').find('> .js-accordion-body').show();
        },
        toggle: function($this) {

          if(settings.oneOpen && $this[0] != $this.closest('.js-accordion').find('> .js-accordion-item.active > .js-accordion-header')[0]) {
            $this.closest('.js-accordion')
                   .find('> .js-accordion-item') 
                   .removeClass('active')
                   .find('.js-accordion-body')
                   .slideUp()
          }

          // show/hide the clicked accordion item
          $this.closest('.js-accordion-item').toggleClass('active');
          $this.next().stop().slideToggle(settings.speed);
        }
      }
    })();

    $(document).ready(function(){accordion.init({ speed: 300, oneOpen: true });});
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 5em;
}

.accordion {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion-header,
.accordion-body {
  background: white;
}

.accordion-header {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #6F277D;
  background: #9E38B0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.accordion-header:hover {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.accordion-body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  color: #3f3c3c;
  display: none;
}

.accordion-body__contents {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.accordion__item.active:last-child .accordion-header {
  border-radius: none;
}

.accordion:first-child > .accordion__item > .accordion-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.accordion__item > .accordion-header:after {
  content: "\f3d0";
  font-family: IonIcons;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  transition: .3s all;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion__item.active > .accordion-header:after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion-header {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
}

.accordion__item .accordion__item .accordion-header {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .accordion {
    width: 100%;
  }
}body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 5em;
}

.accordion {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion-header,
.accordion-body {
  background: white;
}

.accordion-header {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #6F277D;
  background: #9E38B0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.accordion-header:hover {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.accordion-body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  color: #3f3c3c;
  display: none;
}

.accordion-body__contents {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.accordion__item.active:last-child .accordion-header {
  border-radius: none;
}

.accordion:first-child > .accordion__item > .accordion-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.accordion__item > .accordion-header:after {
  content: "\f3d0";
  font-family: IonIcons;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  transition: .3s all;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion__item.active > .accordion-header:after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion-header {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
}

.accordion__item .accordion__item .accordion-header {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .accordion {
    width: 100%;
  }
}body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 5em;
}

.accordion {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion-header,
.accordion-body {
  background: white;
}

.accordion-header {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #6F277D;
  background: #9E38B0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.accordion-header:hover {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.accordion-body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  color: #3f3c3c;
  display: none;
}

.accordion-body__contents {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.accordion__item.active:last-child .accordion-header {
  border-radius: none;
}

.accordion:first-child > .accordion__item > .accordion-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.accordion__item > .accordion-header:after {
  content: "\f3d0";
  font-family: IonIcons;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  transition: .3s all;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion__item.active > .accordion-header:after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion-header {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
}

.accordion__item .accordion__item .accordion-header {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .accordion {
    width: 100%;
  }
}body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 5em;
}

.accordion {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion-header,
.accordion-body {
  background: white;
}

.accordion-header {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #6F277D;
  background: #9E38B0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.accordion-header:hover {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.accordion-body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  color: #3f3c3c;
  display: none;
}

.accordion-body__contents {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.accordion__item.active:last-child .accordion-header {
  border-radius: none;
}

.accordion:first-child > .accordion__item > .accordion-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.accordion__item > .accordion-header:after {
  content: "\f3d0";
  font-family: IonIcons;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  transition: .3s all;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion__item.active > .accordion-header:after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion-header {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
}

.accordion__item .accordion__item .accordion-header {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .accordion {
    width: 100%;
  }
}body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 5em;
}

.accordion {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion-header,
.accordion-body {
  background: white;
}

.accordion-header {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #6F277D;
  background: #9E38B0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .8em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.accordion-header:hover {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.accordion-body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  color: #3f3c3c;
  display: none;
}

.accordion-body__contents {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.accordion__item.active:last-child .accordion-header {
  border-radius: none;
}

.accordion:first-child > .accordion__item > .accordion-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.accordion__item > .accordion-header:after {
  content: "\f3d0";
  font-family: IonIcons;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  transition: .3s all;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion__item.active > .accordion-header:after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion-header {
  background: #6844B7;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #4C3185;
}

.accordion__item .accordion__item .accordion-header {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .accordion {
    width: 100%;
  }
}/* CSS Document */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion js-accordion">
</div>
```

After skimming your demo, I've included your CSS into my example.

Comment: I am currently only using min.js. The HTML seems over complicated but I need these tags to animate it using jquery. Here is a link to the live version of my code http://vynl.space/Projects/accord/

Comment: I have managed to get something to display but all it says is **UNDEFINED**. I have edited the code at the top so you can see what I have done. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Thats a good first step, update your answer with what you have now. I'll be tweaking the answer with your css.

Comment: Good updates, be sure to refer to my first point and change `$.each(data, function(index, element) {` to `$.each(data.blocks, function(index, element) {` as there is a `blocks` property first in your data.

Comment: Thank you Phillip that worked. The only problem is that all of the data is showing in each of the elements for example each head says "Section 1 Section 2 Section 3". Do you know how I would get each piece of data to display in its own div?

Comment: Check my answer now, I'm betting this will get everything sorted out. It involves using your custom accordion initialization after the ajax results are appended to the DOM.

Comment: All looked good but now i get this error : net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

Comment: Ah, this is probably from me using the https URL for the Ajax. I used it because stack overflow wants to be secure. Change to that to http.

Comment: Sorted, it was Http instead of Https. Thanks again for all of your help.